# How to find out which table row was clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using 'live' function to do some on-click stuff on table rows, i.e.

```
$("tr").live('click',function() {
      alert('Some table row is clicked');
});
```

I want to find out which row is clicked and using `if-else`, give some custom alert based upon that. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT 1:**

Is there a way by which I can refer to the elements of the clicked row inside the function?

Comment: @xFortyFourx: Had you posted your comment as answer, I would have accepted it. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("tr").live('click', function() {
    if (this.id == "foo") {
        alert('the tr with the foo id was clicked');
    }
});​
```

If you want to check which row number, use `index`:

```
$("tr").live('click', function() {
   if $(this).index() === 2) {
     alert('The third row was clicked'); // Yes the third as it's zero base index
   }
});​
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kh9vt/)

---

**Update:**

```
$("tr").live('click', function() {
    // "this" is the clicked <tr> element
    // $(this).find('td span') is the spans inside a td inside the clicked <tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I had another question. Is there a way by which I can refer to the elements of the clicked row inside the function?

Answer (score 2):

First you shouldn't use .live() ever :)

[why you shouldn't use .live()](http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/why-jquery-live-is-a-bad-option-to-use/)

you can use instead .delegate()
**Example**

```
$(document).delegate("tr", "click", function(e) {
 // write your code here 
});
```

Comment: Right , but even you use JQuery < 1.4.3 it's a bad practice to use .live() specially if you use it aloot in your code .

Comment: Thanks Rayan, +1 for the link.

Comment: Btw, do you mean "Ryan Gigs"? :)

Comment: No , my name is "Rayan" and in the same time i like Ryan Giggs :))

Comment: Link is broken now (404).

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest an easy way. Suppose this is your table:

```
<table>
<tr id = '1' class="tr">...</tr>
<tr id = '2' class="tr">...</tr>
<tr id = '3' class="tr">...</tr>
</table>
```

Place this in your jQuery code:

```
$(function(){

$('.tr').click(function(){
var row_no = $(this).attr('id');
alert('Row number '+row_no+' was clicked');
});

});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That's not really jQuery - `this` is the plain DOM element, and `id` is a property every DOM element has. So in this case the direct way to access it is shorter and faster. Besides that, if you prefer to use the jQuery way even to access that property, use `prop` instead of `attr`. `attr` has some magic to detect if you actually want a property instead of an attribute so it's slower. Usually `.prop()` is what you want - there are few cases where you really need `.attr()`

Comment: I've given you +1 for suggesting `this`, but I would really suggest not using numeric ID values.

Answer (score 1):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/zJUuX/

HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr><td>hey</td></tr>
    <tr><td>hi</td></tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
    messages( $(this).index() );
});

    function messages(index) {
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                alert("you clicked 1st row");
                break;
            case 1:
                alert("you clicked 2nd row");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        $("table tr").eq(index).css("background","#ff0");
        $("table tr").eq(index).find("a"); //will find all the nested anchor tags.
    }
```

There you go Learner, now I shall accept my virtual points :D. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I had another question. Is there a way by which I can refer to the elements of the clicked row inside the function?

Comment: $("table tr").eq(index); <- that will get you the selected row, inside the function "messages()"

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the clicked element using `this`.

*offtopic*: $.live is deprecated since 1.7, you should be using $.on. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement on gdoron's answer jQuery's live() is deprecated, try `delegate` or `on`:

```
$("#mytable").delegate("tr", "click", function(e) {
  if (this == "foo") {
     ....
  }
});
```

Comment: If you cannot use `.on()` there is no reason to use a delegate on the document instead of `.live()`. It was only deprecated in favor of `.on()`, not in favor of `.delegate()` (which is also deprecated since `.on()` was added)

Comment: @ThiefMaster. `delegate` wasn't deprecated (yet...)

Comment: Well ok, it's just been superseded. But I'd say if you have 1.7 you can treat it like it's actually deprecated.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, from the documentation: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: Yes, because using delegate on an element as close as possible to the elements you want the events from is better. But adding a delegate to `document` is actually the same as adding a live event.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Even row
$("tr:even").click(function() {
    alert('Even');
});

//Odd row
$("tr:odd").click(function() {
    alert('Odd');
});​
```